# Summing unstructured 'blocks' of numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a column of data in the following general format:

```
2000
1000
500
300
1500

c
a


1000
1500
1250
3000


4000
6500

3000

1000
1000
1000

f


4500
1500
3000
3000
2000
```

There is no pattern to the number of entries in each 'block', the number of spaces between blocks, or the number of non-numeric characters between blocks. What I would like to be able to do is sum each of the 'blocks and place the result beside its respective block. Is there a way to do this without VBA?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),NOT(ISNUMBER(A3))),SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl-D` in Excel to 'Fill Down' if the column is long and you don't want to scroll to find the end to copy down.